# Regression Proof

Tags: statistics, regression, conditional-probability

If the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by: $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
1/2,  & \text{for } |x| + |y| \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}  \\ \end{cases}$$
Show that $Y$ has constant regression with respect to $X$ and/but that $X$ and $Y$ are not independant.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $Y|X=x$ does not depend on x and $E(Y|X)=EY$. This I believe says that $Y$ has a constant regression with respect to $X$. But wouldn't they also have to be independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(X,Y)$ is uniform on the square with vertices $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$, conditionally on $[X=x]$, $Y$ is uniform on its intersection with $\{x\}\times\mathbb R$, that is, uniform on the interval $(-1+|x|,1-|x|)$. In particular $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=0$ while $(X,Y)$ is not independent.

Comment: So would that mean $f_X(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ on the interval $(-1+|y|,1-|y|)$? When I work  out the marginal densities I don't get this. Also could you please expand on why $E[Y|X]=0$

Comment: *So would that mean fX(x) is 12 on the interval (−1+|y|,1−|y|)?*... Yes. *When I work out the marginal densities I don't get this*... Then show how you work them out and what you get. *Also could you please expand on why E[Y|X]=0*... Basically because the conditional distribution of Y conditionally on X=x is symmetric.

Comment: solving for the marginal distribution of $f_X(x)$ I get $-\int_{-1+|x|}^0\frac{1}{2}dy+\int_0^{1-|x|}\frac{1}{2}dy$ is this the correct way to set it up?